# Custom ajax send mail form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I got this HTML form code :

```
        <form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form">
            <div class="row  wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" required>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Enter your message" required></textarea>
            </div>                        
            <div class="form-group">
              <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Send Now</button>
            </div>
          </form>
```

and the corresponding jQuery code which I think it sends the informations :

```
// Contact form
var form = $('#main-contact-form');     
form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn() );
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

When I submit the form I got nothing in my webmail. Can anyone spot the problem ?

Thanks

Comment: In your browser's debugging tools, is the AJAX request being made?  Does it have the data you expect it to?  What is the server's response?  I'm not really seeing where in the code any data is actually being sent to the server.  Nor have you included any server-side code which actually *sends* an email...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you should have told me you want to use ajax. So you should do this :

In jour jQuery :

```
// Contact form
var form = $('#main-contact-form');     
form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var name = $('#name').val();
    var subject = $('#subject').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var message = $('#message').val();          

    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: {name: name, subject:subject, email:email, message:message }, 
        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn() );
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

and in your HTML leave it as it is.

Tell me if it helped.